# Vim youcompleteme ycm doesn't work for the file without an extension such like .gitignore

Tags: vim, youcompleteme

When I input the path or file name in .gitignore, the ycm cannot be triggered. How can I config or enable it?
eg.
vim .gitginore
When I input a path in .gitginore, the popup is not triggered.

Below is the config for ycm:

```
autocmd InsertLeave * if pumvisible() == 0|pclose|endif "close windows when out of insert mode
"inoremap <expr> <CR> pumvisible() ? "\<C-y>" : "\<CR>"    "Key enter to select
let g:ycm_collect_identifiers_from_tags_files=1
let g:ycm_min_num_of_chars_for_completion=2
let g:ycm_seed_identifiers_with_syntax=1
let g:ycm_complete_in_comments = 1 "complete in comment
let g:ycm_complete_in_strings = 1 "complete in string
let g:ycm_collect_identifiers_from_comments_and_strings = 1 "search comment and string
let g:ycm_confirm_extra_conf = 0
let g:ycm_key_invoke_completion = '<C-x>'
```

Comment: More details please

Comment: How can I answer without info?

Comment: Anyway I can give more information? thank you:)